# Join two tables to get all data

Tags: sql, join

Suppose I have two tables:

Table 1

```
Col
1
3
4
5
6
9
```

and Table 2

```
Col
2
4
6
8
```

How can I Merge the two tables so I have 1-9 and if a number only appears in one table, the corresponding position in the other table has a null? Thank you.

Comment: What abut `UNION` ? do you have only one column ?

Comment: MySQL? SQL Server? ...?

Comment: please add the required output

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want the numbers that actually exist in at least one of the tables, which won't give you a row with `7`;

What you're looking for seems to be something like a `FULL OUTER JOIN` which works in pretty much any RDBMS except MySQL;

```
SELECT a.col col_a, b.col col_b
FROM Table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 b ON a.col = b.col
ORDER BY COALESCE(a.col, b.col);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9f2d/1).

Sadly, MySQL does not have `FULL OUTER JOIN`, so you'll have to do the same operation using a `UNION` between a `LEFT JOIN` and a `RIGHT JOIN`;

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT a.col col_a, b.col col_b
  FROM Table1 a
  LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON a.col = b.col
  UNION
  SELECT a.col col_a, b.col col_b
  FROM Table1 a
  RIGHT JOIN Table2 b ON a.col = b.col
)z
ORDER BY COALESCE(col_a, col_b);
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9f2d/4).

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong. you need records from both table. (please correct me if i am wrong)

Try following to get data from both tables:

```
select col from Table1
union
select col from Table2

select col from Table1
union all
select col from Table2
```

**NOTE:**
`UNION` removes duplicate records (where all columns in the results are the same), `UNION ALL` does not.

There is a performance hit when using `UNION vs UNION ALL`, since the database server must do additional work to remove the duplicate rows, but usually you do not want the duplicates (especially when developing reports).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one using union:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT col AS value FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT col AS value FROM table2)t1
ORDER BY value
```

try and post your comments:

Thanks